# index.html changes does not reflect on browser using expo web

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-web

I have generated index.html by using `npx expo customize` the output was placed in `web/index.html` when I change this static file. It doesn't reflect on browser with the command `expo start --web`. I think this is only for build purposes and does not help with development hot-update. Is there any way I can reflect changes in index.html to development ?